# Exiting node.js command line app with SIGINT

Tags: node.js, sigint

Is this at all correct?

```
var sigintCount = 0;

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('Got your SIGINT => Press Control-C *twice* to exit.');
    sigintCount++;
    if(sigintCount > 1){
        process.exit();   //what is an appropriate exit code?
    }
});
```

and what exit code should I use?

Comment: Up to you...0 if it exited normally (the default), 1 if it errored out, 2+ if you want to specify something special.

Comment: `nodejs process` does not emit any event named `SIGINT`. However if it were, your code should work. Although you might want to put a `connected` check before exit so it doesn't throw any excepions.

Comment: There must be an accepted exit code for processes killed by a SIGINT?

Comment: Check this so http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99117